# Why does the expression {x}.x throw error by itself, but within an expression it doesn't?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have been reading about [object initialization on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions) and came across the following example:

```js
const a = "foo";
const b = 42;
const c = {};

// Shorthand property names
const o = { a, b, c };

// In other words,
console.log(o.a === { a }.a); // true
```

What is surprising to me is that `{a}.a` gives error by itself:

```js
const a = "foo";
const b = 42;
const c = {};

// Shorthand property names
const o = { a, b, c };

// In other words,
console.log(o.a === { a }.a); // true

console.log({a}.a); // all good
"foo"; //all good
//but the following gives error
{a}.a;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `{` after `===` starts an [object initilizer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) which creates an object.

You can put `.a` after an object to access a property of it.

---

A statement that **starts** with a `{` is a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).

You *can't* put a `.a` after a block. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Alnitak — It starts with a `(` not a `{`.

Comment: What is happening with `console.log({a}.a)`  or `({a}.a)` in general. Does it become an object [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: I think the more relevant part is that after === the interpreter is already expecting an _expression_.

Comment: @user31782 — No. It's an object initialiser. To be a destructuring assignment it would need to be a function parameter or the LHS of an assignment.